# Spring applications can't communicate when put in Docker

Tags: spring, rest, docker, docker-compose

I have 2 spring REST applications (gateway/security) that communicate with each other.

When I send a login request to the gateway, the gateway forwards it to the security application where it is checked whether the user has the correct rights. if this is the case, an account will be returned. This works great on my local pc, but when I put it in docker it stops working.

**I tried:**

- Sending via POSTMAN a post request direct to the security server, this works
- Sending via POSTMAN a post request direct to the gateway with the wrong data to check if I got a custom made error, this worked too.
- Using it without using docker, this worked.

My docker-compose looks like.

[image: this]

Code where I think it goes wrong (This is in the gateway application when I try to send it to the security application):
[image]

If I need to provide more data, let me know

Comment: You seem to have attached screen shots of your `docker-compose.yml` file and Java code to the question.  Can you replace these with the actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong way of doing it. First thumb rule of docker is not to use `localhost` at all.

You need to use the name of the service in your docker compose and you should depend on docker container to container communication.

So in your case the url should be like below

```java
String url = "http://security:8083/auth/login";
```

Also as best practice never write urls directly into your code. Always take them using `application.properties` in your code and then later override them using the environment variables. This make sure that your code can run in different environments by just overriding environment variables and they don't need a code change